# Drupal 7 : Connect & Run 2 MySQL simultaneously

Tags: php, mysql, drupal, drupal-7

I want to connect and run 2 database simultaneously because I want my CMS read some data from other database. Is there any way to run it?

My settings.php

```html
  $databases = array();
  $databases['default']['default'] = array(
      'driver' => 'mysql',
      'database' => 'portal',
      'username' => 'root',
      'password' => 'root',
      'host' => 'localhost',
      'prefix' => 'drupal_',
    );

  $databases['default']['test'] = array(
      'driver' => 'mysql',
      'database2' => 'systems',
      'username' => 'root',
      'password' => 'root',
      'host' => 'localhost',
      'prefix' => '',
    );
```

I tried to change drupal db snippet but it won't work. My data from 'systems' not found.

Sorry for my bad english.

database.inc

```html
// Character set is added to dsn to ensure PDO uses the proper character
    // set when escaping. This has security implications. See
    // https://www.drupal.org/node/1201452 for further discussion.
    $dsn .= ';charset=' . $charset;
    $dsn .= ';dbname=' . $connection_options['database']['database2'];
```

Answer (score 0):

You have database array defined as "default" inside "default" and second as "test" inside "default".

I used different array structure:

"default" inside "default" and 
"default" inside "test"
and that works for me, so try changing that second db definition to:

```
  $databases['test']['default'] = array(
```

Comment: tried changed  it, but it won't work for me. plus i have two database named portal and systems. Portal is all good. but Systems can't. I can't combine it these databases since it's client demands.

Comment: I would suggest first to try with systems db only and see if that is actually working with your setup or not? If that is then we should see the other solutions. Also, would you be able to provide more details where you are changing the DB connection in code to pull data from the systems database? That code might also have some glitch.

Comment: Are you using connection switcher db_set_active('test'); while fetching data from systems DB?

Comment: Yes it worked if I changed to the 'test' db and shows data. But my cms won't load the content without 'portal' db. :-/.

Comment: I have no clue how to change database inside drupal. So I tried database.inc with this line 49 $dsn .= ';dbname=' . $connection_options['database']. I tried to change it to 'database2' following on Settings.php